# jquery add new li to nested set model

Tags: jquery, nested-sets, nested-set-model

What is the best way to insert a new li element into a specific position of a nested set model?

For example, the following list:

```
<ol class="nested">
    <li id="list_1"></li>
    <li id="list_2">
        <ol>
            <li id="list_3"></li>
            <li id="list_4"></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li id="list_5"></li>
</ol>
```

Let's say I want to insert a new li as a child of #list_2
I can do like that:

```
$('#list_'+parent_ID+' ol > li:last-child').after('<li id=""></li>');
```

But wouldn't work if parent was going to be #list_1 or #list_4
Any ideas !?

Comment: So if you apply this function to `<li id="list_2">` you end up with `<li id="list_2"><ol><li></li><li></li><li>new li</li></ol></li>` but if you apply it to `<li id="list_1"></li>` you get  `<li id="list_1"><ol><li>new ol and li</li></ol></li>`?

Comment: @artlung that's what i'm looking for, yes =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. One may be this:

```
if ($('#list_'+parent_ID+' ol').length > 0) {
  $('#list_'+parent_ID+' ol > li:last-child').after('<li id=""></li>');
} else {
  $('#list_'+parent_ID).append('<ol><li id=""></li></ol>');
}
```

You can [test here](http://jsfiddle.net/bQt9f/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMG5G/4/) might be what you are looking for?! If there already is an `<ol>` inside the parent element, the `<li>` is appended. If the parent `<li>` is empty, a new `<ol>` is created before the new child is appended to it.

```
function appendItemToList(parentId) {
    var $thelist = $("#list_"+parentId),
        $ol = $thelist.find("> ol");

    if(!$ol.length) {
        $ol = $("<ol />").appendTo($thelist);
    }
    $ol.append("<li id=''></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [iff](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-iff-plugin/)  plugin -

```
var parent_ID = 1;
$('#list_' + parent_ID).
    iff($(this).children('ol').length > 0)
    .append("<li>new</li>").end()
    .iff($(this).children('ol').length == 0)
    .append("<ol><li>new</li></ol>");
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MUcbW/2/

Comment: Nice chainable if statement, did not know... Also good answer, had to accept the first one though. Thank you ipr101

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, adding the appropriate elements on click:

```
$('ol.nested > li').bind('click', function(){
    var elem;
    if ($('ol', this).length > 0) {
        elem = $(this).find('ol');
    } else {
        elem = $('<ol>').appendTo($(this));
    }
    elem.append("<li>new</li>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Ivan had came up with the same idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in one line like:

```
$('#list_' + parentId).contents().andSelf().filter('li').last().after('<li id=""></li>');
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/TSBKY/